# ListView in a TextView from a method (Not Main Thread UI)

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I want to make a list from outside of the main thread, in a method. But compiler says me that setListAdapter is undefined. What I am doing wrong?

```
public void getVenues() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(getQUERY_4SQ(), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFinish();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        makeToast("Charged Categories", 1);
                    }
                });

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // storing string resources into Array
                        String[] name_venues;
                        for(int i = 0; i < listVenues.size(); i++){
                            name_venues[i] = listVenues.get(i).getName();
                        }

                        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
                        MainActivity.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_venues, R.id.venueListUI, name_venues));

                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is MainActivity extending? ListActivity, Activity,...? You can simply store the ListView in "mListView" for example and call mListView.setAdapter(something something);

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener

Comment: Make it a `ListActivity` and it should work. Otherwise you have to make a `ListView` object and call `setAdapter(...)` on it.